# Pass parameter by reference vs use Instance variable

Tags: c++, reference, instance-variables

I started to read a book about C++ and found the following code. 
It is an example on how you can send pass parameters by reference.

```
#include <iostream>

void swap(int &x, int &y);

int main()
{
    int x = 5, y = 10;

    std::cout << "Main. Before swap, x: " << x
              << " y: " << y << "\n";
    swap(x, y);
    std::cout << "Main. After swap, x: " << x
              << " y: " << y << "\n";
    return 0;
}

void swap(int &rx, int &ry)
{
    int temp;

    std::cout << "Swap. Before swap, rx: " << rx
              << " ry: " << ry << "\n";

    temp = rx;
    rx = ry;
    ry = temp;

    std::cout << "Swap. After swap, rx: " << rx
              << " ry: " << ry << "\n";
}
```

.

```
Main. Before swap, x:5 y: 10
Swap. Before swap, rx:5 ry:10
Swap. After swap, rx:10 ry:5
Main. After swap, x:10, y:5
```

The logic is clear to me. 
Now this may be a very stupid question (I'm not very experienced yet), but why can't you just declare private: int x as an instance variable? Isn't x in this case directly accessible everywhere in your class? (without the need for specifying parameters at all)? Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: Please don't use line numbers in your code - it makes copy and paste to try it out *really* hard. If you want to refer to specific lines indicate them with a comment is much better.

Comment: What class are you talking about? There is no class (or event struct) in the code you posted.

Comment: Who's talking about classes? I don't see any classes. Are you a Java programmer?

Comment: And don't copy paste code found on the web or from MS Word or similar (it f*cks up the quote characters badly). FTFY

Comment: lol Okay -> It is copy paste from a book, so I'll leave out the numbers next time. The whole piece of code is a class called "ValuePasser.cpp". Sorry, I'll take it into account for the next time!

Comment: @user: that's not a class, that's a filename.

Comment: Err.. yeah, sorry about that too, I guess it's clear what I mean...

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean. There are no classes in the code you've posted, yet your question is about member variables.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I didn't pay attention to this. I'm used to Xcode before I started C++, where you have header and implementation files. You don't actually type "class className{}" there, the .h and .m files immediately define the class... In the book, they didn't specify the classname explicitly either, probably since they took this piece of code as an illustration. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For several reasons.

1. You should declare variables at the narrowest [scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_programming%29) possible. Why? Look at 2 & 3
2. Variables are expensive, they take up memory, you only want them
   around as long as you need them.
3. The greater a variables [scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_programming%29) (i.e. how much code the variable is visible
   to) the greater the chance that you will mistakenly use the
   variable, and therefore it's value may change unexpectedly. This will be a bug, good luck hunting that one down.
4. [Tight coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_science%29) (this is bad). If you write a class and put a swap method on the
   class, and you write it so it uses instance member x (not method
   variable x), then that swap method *CAN ONLY EVER* swap using x, if
   in time you need it to swap on a different variable (or the
   parameter of another method on the class) then you've to move the
   value into x which is Inefficient & `goto 5`. Isn't it better to call the swap function with the values you have to hand, without needing to know there's a special x variable that you have to set first?
5. Error prone. Will this second method be called while another method
   is using the swap method? What should the value of x be after it's
   called? You're introducing lots of context around swap and knowing when it's
   ok to call swap, and what can call swap. This is bad, the more self contained any piece of code is, then the less of have to worry about it, and about how it's used.
6. No other class can re-use your swap method, every class that needs a
   swap method must implement it's own, and this is a **huge big
   no-no** for more reasons than I can count here, but can sum up as it
   voliates the [DRY Principal](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontRepeatYourself)

All of these problems can be removed by simply passing the values by reference. Bit of a no-brainer really :)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks as well. I excepted your answer since it is definitely the most complete one :-)

Answer (score 1):

Passing values via arguments to a function ensures modularity in your code. It sounds like you're just starting out with C++, so I'm not sure how familiar you are with object oriented programming. Functions/methods represent a layer of [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29). Your swap() function should encapsulate the logic needed to perform its function/purpose. The caller should not be concerned with how this is accomplished. If your swap() function must assert there is a global variable available in the program, then it's not fully encapsulating the logic of "swapping".

Also, Lets say you wanted to reuse this function elsewhere in your class. It would be difficult and clumsy to use a set of global variables for calling this function. In addition, you may have other locations in your class that are referencing those global variables, and therefore your other calls to swap() would change those values, potentially causing confusion in other areas of the code.

Comment: You are right, I started with Objective C only a couple of months ago for the purpose of making apps in Xcode. I got interested in C++ though and I want to learn more. Your answer made it very clear, thanks for that!